Error while trying to Publish with MassTransit and AzureServiceBus
I'm currently using AzureServiceBus and wanted to implement MassTransit. Queues are not relevant to me, since I'm only using topics and subscriptions. All my topics and subscriptions are already created and I don't plan on changing that because we're deploying those seperatly.
When I want to publish a message to a specific topic, I always get following error:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature. 
[...]
Status: 401 (Unauthorized)

If I send the message normally with the specific AzureServiceBus implementation I don't get these errors. I also tried the mediator Wolverine and it send the messages without any of those Authorization problems.
My Program.cs MassTransit code looks like this:
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(configure =>
{
    configure.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, opt) =>
        {
            opt.Host("Endpoint=sb://<name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<name-of-key-name>;SharedAccessKey=<key>", con =>
            {
                con.TransportType = Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
            });

            opt.Message<MessageClassRequest>(m => m.SetEntityName("topic-name"));
});

In my service class I inject the IBus and call await bus.Publish(message, cancellationToken);
The SharedAccessKeyName has the permission to Manage, Send and Listen. But MassTransit should not even create the topic or subscription.
My end goal is to send a message to a topic that has multiple subscriptions. Those subscriptions filter their messages with a subject/label correclation filter so I also need to be able to change that attribute in the message.
But so far I can't even seem to send a normal message to a subscription without any filters. What am I missing here?
